# Is it grammatically correct to say “In den nächsten zwei Wochen”?

Tags: article, time

I going through a lot of confusion lately with the articles in the German language.

Is it grammatically correct to say “In den nächsten zwei Wochen” instead of “In  nächsten zwei Wochen”?

What are the other cases where one might omit the article?

Answer (score 4):

It is grammatically correct to say *in **den** nächsten zwei Wochen;* it is not correct to omit the article.

In German, the idea is that you are speaking about two definite following weeks *(the* two weeks following) similarly to English. Other languages may think differently and consider *next two weeks* definite enough.

Comment: Fails to answer question concerning omission of article, see [German canoo.net](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Artikel/Gebrauch/Ohne.html).

Comment: @guidot I corrected the question’s incorrect premise. I consider the second part of the question moot (since the original premise was incorrect) or too broad (since it touches something entirely differently). Hence I did not answer it.